# How to deal with [h] coefficients which are 0 from sos-matrix

Tags: python, butterworth

Calling `scipy.signal.sosfreqz` with a sos-matrix describing an ordinary butterworth bandpass returns an array of `h` coefficients, of which the one at index `0` is of value `0.0+j0.0`. A problem arises when the filter needs to be scaled to `0dB` plotted via

```
plt.semilogx(f, np.array([20 * m.log10(abs(value)) for value in h]), label=None)
```

which runs into a `ValueError: math domain error` because the first `h`-value causes `log10(0)` which does not exist. Matlab somehow handles this implicitly. How could i modify/ignore `h[0]` in a scientifically correct manner?

Python code to reproduce:

```
sample_f = 48000
nyquist = sample_f / 2
_sos = signal.butter(6, [18245 / nyquist , 22988 / nyquist], btype='band', output='sos')
f, h = signal.sosfreqz(_sos,worN=sample_f)
print(abs(h[0])) # is zero
plt.semilogx(f, np.array([20 * m.log10(abs(value)) for value in h]), label=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer for at these frequencies is $-\infty$ which of course you can't plot.

Two ways of dealing with it:

1. Add a small offset that's related to the dynamic range you want to see. Something like `h[0] = 1e-10` would cap the plot at -200dB.
2. Just exclude the offending frequency from your plot. Something like `semilogx(f[1:],h[1:])`

Comment: 2. answer seals the deal!